# Subadditivity of outer measure on real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the field of measure theory, the outer measure is defined on the set of real numbers as:

$$m^{*}(A) = \inf\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} l(E_n): \space A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \right\} $$

NOTE - $l(E_n)$ is the length of the interval $E_n$

I want to show that the real number outer measure is subadditive, so

$$m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n \right) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}(S_n)$$

As a first step in the proof, all the measure theory textbooks I have consulted start by stating that we assume that $m^*(S_n)$ is finite for all $n$ (because the result is trivially true otherwise), which makes sense to me.

Next, they assert that for any $S_n$, we can find an open cover $\space S_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ such that $ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} l(E_n) \le \mu^*(S_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$

Why does such a cover necessarily exist? Isn't it possible that the only covers are countably infinite on the real numbers? Also, what explains the epsilon inequality - how do we know that a countable cover necessarily meets that criterion?

Comment: "countably infinite on the real numbers" What does this mean?

Comment: The collection of covers is non-empty since we could cover by the whole space. We defined the value of the outer measure as the infimum of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(E_{i})$ over all possible covers. We can find a cover with the properties you mentioned since we can come arbitrarily close to the infimum. If the only possible covers all have infinite sum then the infimum will be infinite so the above estimate has no contradiction.

Comment: see also the answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810745/outer-measure-is-countably-subadditive